# where to set default font size of entire web site, Jekyll, bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll and Bootstrap-3 style and would like to increase the default font size for 14px to about 20px if possible for the entire web site.  I found a setting for something called "body" in the page source code.  It appears to be set in a file called
/project/assets/bootstrap-3/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.  I'm speculating that I could make changes in there but have seen it suggested not to edit this file.  Is there an easy way to create a new .css file, that will be called by jekyll that will set the default font size to 20px?

Comment: body { font-size: 20px; }

Comment: Thanks for that ... but where do I put this?  If I don't edit the bootstrap.min.css file ... where do I put it or do I have to edit this file?  Thanks

Comment: If you using bootstrap then edit bootstrap css, find `body` in css and edit `font-size` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll will find about 56 occurrences of *font-size* in bootstrap.css. All are computed by Less preprocessor. Don't try to directly edit the css this can arm your style proportions.

If you want a custom bootstrap, you can go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and change @font-size-base and then download you're customized version.

You can also learn less or sass to use the power of css preprocessors with Jekyll (native Sass processing) and bootstrap.